# Como colocar classe active na navbar

Tags: jquery, css, html5

Estou tentando colocar uma classe active no navbar, estou usando bootstrap, o que acontece é que quando clico na li chega a aparecer a cor do background porém logo some. Segue o código que estou usando
o css:

```
 .navbar-nav > .active  {   
 background-color: green !important; 
 }
```

o jquery

```
$('ul.navbar-nav > li ').click(function() {
    $('ul.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

o html

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-
        toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" 
        href="#">Serviços</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="dados.html">Dados</a></li>
                <li><a href="ficha.html">ficha</a></li>
            /ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="noticias.html">Notícias</a></li>
        <li><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Coloca o código HTML também

Answer (score 1, accepted):

não, tá errado isso ai, você saiu da home e foi para outra pagina que nada tem haver, você tá usando html, ele não vai saber onde você clicou na pagina anterior.

você não vai acionar nada no click, você vai **retirar a class active** do elemento anterior e alocá-la em outro elemento da seguinte forma:

insira isto no final de todas as paginas, substituindo `homelink` pelo id do link da home e substituindo `aboutlink` pelo id do link que recebe a classe active:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('aboutlink').classList.add('active'); // Adiciona classe

    document.getElementById('homelink').classList.remove('active'); // Remove classe
</script>
```

No seu menu, você vai definir um id para cada link, dessa forma:

```
  <li class="nav-item active" id="homelink">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item" id="aboutlink">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">about</a>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Altere seu css por

```
 .navbar-nav  .active  {   
     background-color: green !important; 
 }
```

E seu script por

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.navbar-nav li ').click(function() {
       $('.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active'); 
   }); 
});
```

[Veja um exemplo  aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/rsr0h57h/1/)

Comment: pois é vi que funciona direitinho no seu mas aqui não da :/

Comment: alterou o  css ? tente apertar o  ctrl + f5 no  navegador

Comment: sim, esta igual ao seu, botei para debugar e vi que quando carrega a página o breakpoint já para na função do click como se ao carregar clicasse automatico, estranho

Comment: tente chamar o  script no  onload

Comment: alterei o codigo olha ai

Comment: botei, o que acontece, ele bota a classe mas ao sair do }); some a classe, só pode ser coisa do bootstrap

Comment: hmmm deve ter algum nav-bar li:hover no  seu  css, pois quando  vc tira o mouse ele remove o  active do  sue css

Comment: verifiquei os hover e esta só os do bootstrap, tirei eles mas mesmo assim continua esse bug